# How to display date and the author of the last revision for a page that is currently being viewed?

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress Admin for every page and post there is a 'Revision' section.

**How can I get/display in information (author's name, date) when the last revision was made for a page that is currently being viewed?**

So i'm viewing page 'About us' and whant display this information (author's name, date) for this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last revision is the date of the post was last modified : you should try the_modified_date().
If the post or page is not yet modified, the modified date is the same as the creation date.
(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date)

```
<?php the_modified_author(); ?>, last modified: <?php the_modified_date(); ?>
```

Comment: the_modified_date() works but the_author() is showing author of the page, not author of the last Revision.

Comment: So you could use the_modified_author(); I update ma first post.